# adding second variable to php exec comaand is not working

Tags: php, bash, variables, exec

i am using the following command to help me create needed data

```
exec("awk -F: '{printf \"www.example.com/2/tasks.php?account=%s%%3A%s\\n\" ,$1, $2 }' < /opt/lampp/htdocs/$filename > /opt/lampp/htdocs/2.txt");
```

this works absoloutly fine but when i try to use a second variable i created and issused this exec command it does not output to the second variable the text file is created but nothing there

```
exec("awk -F: '{printf \"www.example.com/2/tasks.php?account=%s%%3A%s\\n\" ,$1, $2 }' < /opt/lampp/htdocs/$filename > /opt/lampp/htdocs/$filename2");
```

can any body help

Comment: Can you post an example input file and the value of `$filename` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `escapeshellarg()` to escape your input, because your variable name might be expanding before being passed into `exec`

Comment: +1 `escapeshellarg()` is a MUST HAVE when passing PHP variables into shell command lines. For security and functionality reasons